# golang templates not working with httprouter

Tags: go, nested, go-templates

I've created nested templating that works when I use "net/http" and http.HandelFunc , however, I've decided to use     "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" going forward as I want to have move flexibility and now my templates don't work, I get a 404 error.

Please, can you help?

**Directory structure**

```
/
/main.go
/templates
/templates/tstats/file.go.html
```

**This code works**

```
func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.go.html"))
}
http.HandleFunc("/tstats/", serveTemplate)

func serveTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    lp := filepath.Join("templates", "layout.html")
    fp := filepath.Join("templates", filepath.Clean(r.URL.Path))
    gh := filepath.Join("templates", "INC_Header.go.html")
    gn := filepath.Join("templates", "INC_Nav.go.html")
    gf := filepath.Join("templates", "INC_Footer.go.html")
    //log.Println(r.URL.Path)

tpl, err := template.ParseFiles(lp, fp, gh, gn, gf)
if err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout", nil); err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
}
```

**The new code that is producing a 404**

```
func serveTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ 
    httprouter.Params) {
    lp := filepath.Join("templates", "layout.html")
    fp := filepath.Join("templates", filepath.Clean(r.URL.Path))
    gh := filepath.Join("templates", "INC_Header.go.html")
    gn := filepath.Join("templates", "INC_Nav.go.html")
    gf := filepath.Join("templates", "INC_Footer.go.html")
    //log.Println(`enter code here`r.URL.Path)

    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(lp, fp, gh, gn, gf)
    if err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout", nil); err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(500), 500)
   }
```

Comment: I hope you mean `http.HandleFunc`, not [`http.HandelFunc`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71NCzuDNUcg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revising after the comment response**. I had a look https://play.golang.org/p/iHUqZQQcv3

You have following issues:

1. Router handler register issue `r.GET("/tstats/", serveTemplate)` - It will only match `http://localhost:8080/tstats/` rest everything is `404`

   - For e.g.: 404 -> `http://localhost:8080/tstats/myfile1.html`
2. The way you calculate the template path file `filepath.Join("templates", filepath.Clean(r.URL.Path))`

Honestly it is very hard to guess, how you're planning/designing your application. Anyway-

Update your code like below:

- Change `/tstats/` => `/tstats/*tmpl` in the router mapping
- Change `fp := filepath.Join("templates", filepath.Clean(r.URL.Path))` => `fp := filepath.Join("templates", "tstats", params.ByName("tmpl"))`

Now, for the request http://localhost:8080/tstats/myfile1.html. It will look for template here `templates/tstats/myfile1.html`.

---

**(This was initial response)**

It seems like `HandlerFunc` register issue that leading to 404.

I have created sample from your code, can you try https://play.golang.org/p/6ilS0htj-I

BTW, I believe; in your first sample code `tpl` variable in the `func init` is not used. Since you have local variable of same name in the `serveTemplate`.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer I've only been using Go for about 4 weeks so pretty new. I tried out your solution but still got the same 404 error..

Comment: For 404, it's surely your router assignment/creation issue. Can you put your code on play.golang.org and share it? I will have a look.

Comment: Hay, it's here. I've been playing with it so i've commented some stuff out. https://play.golang.org/p/iHUqZQQcv3